# How can I get answers of my most curious questions?

Tags: discussion, support

2-3 of my answers are marked either opinion based or the answers their don't justify fully.

Following the rules of site is at one side, but knowing the truth related to Hinduism is not a wrong.

Here are the questions I'm still expecting answers:

[Did Karna think that it was adharma to not appoint Duryodhana as king of Hastinapura?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/35755/did-karna-think-that-it-was-adharma-to-not-appoint-duryodhana-as-king-of-hastina)

[Why Krishna wanted to support Pandavas even when both Pandavas and Karuavas were wrong in dice game?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/35816/why-krishna-wanted-to-support-pandavas-even-when-both-pandavas-and-karuavas-were)

[Would justice, punishment accomplishment and dharma establishment take place irrespective of which side Krishna fought for and which side won?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/35904/would-justice-punishment-accomplishment-and-dharma-establishment-take-place-irr)

If everything were in books, I *wouldn't need* to ask them here.

Again, my motive is to understand the importance of Mahabharata war. It seems unfair to me Krishna supporting Pandavas. According to Balarma, both did adharma. And adharma is not small or big.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you got queries of which answers don't present in scriptures, you need to seek for explanation and interpretation by Acharyas, Gurus, and Swamis. Some open-ended and subjective questions are difficult to answer without personal opinions which can degrade the quality of the site. One of the reasons for your questions remained unanswered would be that the things not discussed in scriptures and no one found an explanation by Acharyas, Gurus or Swamis and hence answering will be posting opinions only.

In such cases, you've two options either put the bounty to draw attention with possibly revising the question to make it answerable or you can discuss with your Guru or Acharyas which is out of the scope of this community.